# Java Right Click does not make a selection. What is the easiest way to solve this globally?

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to globally make right click also select the element that you right click on?

From what I understand this has been a bug in `Swing` for a long time likely to never be fixed because at this point applications depend on it.

Any advice on doing this on a **global scale?  Perhaps on the L&F?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Glass Pane](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) will do the trick.

[Here's a tutorial](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2003/10/swing_hack_4_th.html) on how to use the glass pane to get the right click button and redispatch it to the right component.

---

As the glass pane is not a solution in this case, I suggest you take a look at the [Toolkit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) class. Specificaly the addAWTEventListener method. You can add a global event listener with it. To add a mouse event listener:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
        addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

Cheers

Comment: Glass pane to the rescue again.

Comment: A Glass Pane does not work for my case, but maybe a good answer for someone else.

Comment: Why not? When you say "element" you mean any Swing component? Or elements in a tree or list?

Comment: Both actually, tables, lists, trees, components.  But we also use drag and drop also, which adds another level of issues.  Another issue is we have multiple independent windows for our application.  Ideally if we could set it up on the L&F, but I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: The toolkit looks like it might be the solution.  I will update after I get back to this issue.